# how to find length of string of array of json object in pyspark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have one column in DataFrame with format =
'[{jsonobject},{jsonobject}]'. here length will be 2 .
I have to find length of this array and store it in another column.

Answer (score 0):

I've only worked with pySpark, but the Scala solution would be similar. Assuming the column name is `input`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f, types as t

json_schema = t.ArrayType(t.MapType(t.StringType(), t.StringType()))
df.select(f.size(f.from_json(df.input, json_schema)).alias("num_objects"))
```